# Mostara un mensaje de alerta por contraseña o usuario incorrecto y que el boton aceptar me redireccione denuevo al login

Tags: php, javascript, login, alert, mensajes

Tengo este codigo, estoy utilizando js dentro de php para el mensaje, pero no se como hacer que luego de aparecer el mensaje me redireccione a la pagina del login, o al redireccionarme me aparesca el mensaje.
Este es el codigo de login de php

```
<?php
$usuario_correcto = "seec";
$palabra_secreta_correcta = "1feef4";
$usuario = $_POST["usuario"];
$palabra_secreta = $_POST["palabra_secreta"];
if ($usuario === $usuario_correcto && $palabra_secreta === $palabra_secreta_correcta) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["usuario"] = $usuario;
    header("Location: liberaciones.php");
} else {
    echo "<script language='javascript'>";
    echo "alert('Contraseña incorrecta')";
    echo "</script>";  
    header("Location: login.html");
}

?>
```

Y este el codigo del login html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Inicio de Sesion Liberaciones</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="loginc.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1><strong>MANUAL DE LIBERACIONES</strong><img id="logo" src="imagenes/nrtec.png" width="200" height="100" /></h1>
    <form action="loginp.php" method="post">
    <input name="usuario" type="text" placeholder="Introdusca su usuario">
    <br><br>
    <input name="palabra_secreta" type="password" placeholder="Contraseña">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Iniciar sesión">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

en la parte del `else` de archivo `php` puedes intentar haciendo lo que te muestro a continuación.

primero puedes guardar la ruta en una variable en lugar de usarla directamente, asi luego puedes usar esa variable múltiples veces sin tener que escribir la ruta de nuevo.

luego al `window.location.href` lo igualamos a la url que queremos acceder en este caso a la que guardamos en la variable `filename`

Cuando un nuevo valor es asignado a un objeto location, un documento será cargado usando la URL

tu archivo php te quedaría así:

```
<?php
    $usuario_correcto = "seec";
    $palabra_secreta_correcta = "1feef4";
    $usuario = $_POST["usuario"];
    $palabra_secreta = $_POST["palabra_secreta"];
    if ($usuario === $usuario_correcto && $palabra_secreta === $palabra_secreta_correcta) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["usuario"] = $usuario;
        header("Location: liberaciones.php");
    } else {
        $filename = "login.html";
        echo "<script language='javascript'>";
        echo "alert('Contraseña incorrecta')";
        echo 'window.location.href="'.$filename.'";';
        echo "</script>";  
    }
    
    ?>
```